# Generic repository в WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, рефлексия

Имеется dll, в которой есть сущности и класс для работы с бд (используется рефлексия). Например, у меня обращение в клиенте DataManager.Instance.User.GetList(); Где DataManager это singleton class. Как можно реализовать это в хосте WCF, не могу определить сущность для работы.

```
public class AtelierSevice : IAtelierService
{
    public int Add(T item)
    {
       return DataManager.Instance.User.Add(item);
       DataManager.Instance. //Здесь необходимо узнать к какому репозиторию я обращаюсь
    }

    public void Delete<T>(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public List<T> GetList<T>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update<T>(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Возможно я объяснил не понятно.

Comment: Нет, объяснили понятно. Но и ответ простой: в WCF нельзя дженерики. Совсем. Пишите контракты без дженериков, каждый отдельно для новой таблицы

Comment: @AK возможно тогда как-то работать через object. То есть создать поле в синглтоне и там определять с каким классом работаем

Comment: @AK а если у меня сотня сущностей?

Comment: Ну что вам сказать на это?.. Соболезную.

Comment: У меня встречный вопрос - зачем вы тащите через WCF CRUD-операции? Сделайте на нем нормальный API. В контрактах пропишите действия, соответствующие бизнес-логике, вместо CRUD-операций. А внутри сервиса гоняйте дженерики и все что нравится. Ну либо мучайтесь дальше, микроскопом тоже гвоздь забить можно, только не нужно.

Comment: @rdorn что вы имеете ввиду, говоря, что тащу CRUD-операции через WCF. Просто у меня в отдельной библиотеке работа с базой. Не понимаю, как предоставить пользователю методы из этой библиотеки. Например, я работаю в коде клиента с классом User, передаю данные на изменение, как мне узнать, что я передал именно User. Может глупый вопрос

Comment: @Ari100krat а причем тут WCF, если методы - в библиотеке, а не на сервере?

Comment: @Ari100krat вопрос не глупый, но слишком объемный, для обсуждения в комментариях. См. обновление ответа AK.

Comment: @PavelMayorov имел ввиду предоставить доступ к методам

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В WCF дженерики [не предусмотрены](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2906694/5752652) by design:

> Type 'T' cannot be exported as a schema type because it is an open
>   generic type.

Т.е. вот так не получится у вас:

```
[OperationContract]
void AddItem<T>(T item);
```

PS Если поискать на английском so то вроде как есть пара [сторонних проектов](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5868736/5752652), но сам не пробовал.

PPS Можете написать свой костыль, сериализуя информацию с сохранением информации о том, что за тип был. Но на другой стороне должны уметь работать с этим форматом и производить обратную распаковку.

Update

> что вы имеете ввиду, говоря, что тащу CRUD-операции через WCF. Просто
>   у меня в отдельной библиотеке работа с базой. Не понимаю, как
>   предоставить пользователю методы из этой библиотеки. Например, я
>   работаю в коде клиента с классом User, передаю данные на изменение,
>   как мне узнать, что я передал именно User.

При проектировании приложений принято скрывать реализацию, потому что она может поменяться. База данных – это деталь реализации, легко может поменяться: сегодня MS SQL, завтра Oracle, послезавтра – что-то модное из мира NoSql.

Устройство приложения обычно выглядит следующим образом:

- слой домена. В нём находятся ваши сущности, связанные с моделируемой областью и вся бизнес-логика (и нет никакой работы с базой данных)
- слой работы с базой данных. В нём находятся репозитории, которые понимают как читать и писать в базу ваши модели.
- сервисный слой. В нём находятся сервисы, которые (используют репозитории и) предоставляют приложению методы для работы

Так вот вы предоставляете доступ к слою базы данных (все до единого репозитории) и этим переносите всю логику работы в совершенно неподходящее место. Это как если бы Сбербанк отдал бы вам WCF сервис, которым бы можно было вставлять данные в таблички БД: никакого контроля бизнес-операций, вставляй что хочешь.

Вам нужно предоставлять доступ к слою сервисов. Вы уже запрещаете вставлять данные напрямую в таблицы, но отдаёте методы, которые сами предварительно будут выполнять проверку бизнес-логики и потом уже сами начнут дёргать нужные репозитории.

Comment: Предоставлять доступ к слою сервисов - я так понял вы про "Пишите контракты без дженериков, каждый отдельно для новой таблицы"

Comment: @Ari100krat да что ж вас так на базе-то заклинило. Забудьте про нее. У вас есть (ну по крайней мере должна быть) модель, которой вобщем-то пофигу на то, как ее хранят, и именно ее методы и сущности должны торчать из WCF, а как все это хранить пусть сервис сам разбирается (с вашей помощью разумеется), пользователя или разработчика клиентской части это волновать не должно. Это прекрасно ложится на контракты без дженериков и не содержит сотен однотипных методов. Один метод WCF - одно бизнес-правило.

Comment: @rdorn Видимо я совсем тугой. Да сущности есть и все помечены [DataContract] и [DataMember]. Просто везде примеры вижу как [OperationContract] void Add(User user) - но у меня то не одна сущность User, вот я и попал в ступор. Возможно, рано еще мне это, но я стараюсь

Comment: @Ari100krat вы просто пытаетесь вставить сервис между моделью и репозиториями и это вынуждает делать толстый контракт с сотнями методов, потому что модели нужно получать данные из всех репозиториев. Вставьте сервис между моделью и представлением (клиентским кодом) и потребуется выдать только необходимые методы модели, вместо всех методов репозиториев.

Comment: @rdorn Так, вроде понял. Но что мне решить с моим singleton если можно его так назвать(через него я и обращаюсь в репозиториям). Как мне его в контракт запихнуть, чтобы он был доступен на клиентской стороне

Comment: @Ari100krat он должен остаться внутри сервиса. Снаружи должна быть уже бизнес-логика а не DataManager, ваш DataManager - это слой доступа к данным, модель выше.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72737/discussion-between-rdorn-and-ari100krat).

Comment: @A K можно у тебя спросить совета по одному вопросу?

Comment: @Ari100krat Почему бы не задать на сайте? Или - [в чате .Net](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--)?